# Bootstrap 4 enable navbar collapse on data-toggle only for small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

To collapse the navbar on a mobile screen when a item is clicked I added the data-toggle option. But this is also affecting large screens even though the navbar is not collapsed.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark navbar-toggleable-md">
  <div class="container">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-inverse"></i>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ng-animate-disabled" id="navbarCollapse" ng-if="!header.user">
      <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" href="#!market">Market</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" href="#!pricing">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" href="#!about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to enable the collapse only for large screens.